# Spring inner component class can't use outer class autowired beans

Tags: java, spring

I've come across the issue where inner classes don't recognize the outer class autowired beans.
Can someone explain what is happening here and how to solve it without decoupling the inner class?

```
@Component
public class Outer {

    @Autowired
    private A a;

    public void outer() {
        // a is not null here
    }

    @Component
    public class Inner {

        public void inner() {
            // a is null here
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: How do you get your `Inner` bean?

Comment: This problem is widely known in Spring and is called a bad design :)

Comment: There isn't any explicity injection of the `Inner` bean anywhere in the project. The class only serves as a Spring `@TransactionalEventListener` container, therefore it needs to be picked up by Spring. However, all the methods depend on the `Outer` class autowires.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Yeah, this works fine for me.

Comment: @Savior sorry, what?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], because, with basic assumptions about your code, I can't reproduce the issue you mention.